# Do While: Issue with never ending loop

Tags: c++, c++11, do-while

I am having an issue with my program. I am building a pyramid program to better understand looping structures in C++.
The issue is when I build and run this and I get to:

```
   cout << "\nPlease enter the number of lines for your pyramid: ";
   cin >> height;
```

and I type a random character such as 'K', it starts continuously(never ending) looping:

```
   cout << "ERROR: Please enter a value between 3 and 25!" << endl;
```

My questions: Why does it continuously loop? 
              What can be implemented to fix this issue?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

using namespace std;


void draw(int height)
{
    for(int line = 0;line<=height;line++)
    {
        int spaces = height - line;

        for(int j=1;j<=spaces;j++)
        cout<<" ";
        for(int i=1;i<=line*2+1;i++) 
        cout<<"+";
        cout<<"\n";
    }
}


int main()
{
  int height;
  do{
  cout << "\nPlease enter the number of lines for your pyramid: ";
  cin >> height;
  if(height>3 && height<25)draw(height);

  else{
     cout << "ERROR: Please enter a value between 3 and 25!" << endl;
  }
  }while(height<3 || height>25);
  cout << "\n";

  return 0;
}
```

I have researched and found no similar issues, most common issues seems to be people not setting their conditions.

Comment: You aren't testing the result of reading input.

Comment: You are expecting a `int`, why did you enter a 'K'?

Comment: @herohuyongtao - Users sometimes type in the wrong thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the streaming-input operator `>>` will try to only read input valid for the type you are inputting to:

```
int i;
std::cin >> i;
```

will only read integer values. When this fails, it sets a flag that can be tested for with `std::cin::fail()`

```
int i;
std::cin >> i;
if (cin.fail())
    throw std::invalid_argument("Expected an int, got some other junk");
```

However that leaves the input in the input stream, leaving you to use one of various mechanisms to get around it.

What might be easiest is to use `std::getline` to read the input line-at-a-time.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
#include <cstdlib>

int main() {
    std::string input;
    int i = 0;

    while (std::cin.good()) {
        std::cout << "Enter a number between 3 and 25: ";
        std::getline(std::cin, input);
        if (input.empty()) // blank lines
            continue;
        if (isdigit(input[0])) {
            i = atoi(input.c_str());
            if (i < 3 || i > 25) {
                std::cout << "Invalid number, " << input << '\n';
                continue;
            }
            // valid input, stop the loop
            break;
        }

        std::cout << "Unrecognized/non-numeric input: \"" << input << "\"\n";
    }

    if (i == 0) // we left the loop because cin.good() was false
        return 0;

    std::cout << "You entered " << i << '\n';
}
```

Live demo: http://ideone.com/KRHM3V

Answer (score 2):

This is because you have declared `height` as `int` and whenever `cin` sees a `char` being entered skips without taking the input. So the input stays in the input buffer and `height` retains its older value. In this case its the garbage value and its accidentally not between 3 and 25. Hence the infinte loop.

Use `cin.fail()` if you want to break if a non-integer is entered:

```
int Item;
cin >> Item;
while (! cin.fail())
   {
   Process(Item);
   cin >> Item;
}
```

---

**Edit:** Adding answer based on your comment, input as a string. Check every position for non-digits. And if it is a valid integer, use [atoi()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/) to convert it to an integer.

Comment: Okay well explained. I am expecting the user to type an integer between 3 and 25, my goal was: if the user types a letter or a number outside of 3-25 it will provide an error. It is an easy fix making the int a char but the program no longer functions.

Answer (score 0):

You will have validate if input is valid. Check with code below..

```
if(!(cin >> height))
{
    //print invalid input
    break;
}
```

Also you can check `cin.fail()`

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the `fail` bit after reading the `height`

See - [fail bit](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/fail/)

This is set if it was unable to read an integer. You then need to eat some input and issue a message